# Can I have both full text RSS and an excerpt RSS in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, rss

I like giving my users the full text RSS feed, but I also have a few sites which pull the RSS feed and link to us from it. They want me to provide the excerpt/blurbs for the articles rather than the full text. Can anyone give me some direction on how to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible.  Wordpress has multiple feed types (see [WordPress Feeds](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds)) and there are hooks for each feed type (see [Feed Actions API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Feed_Actions)).  This suggests that you should be able to set up one feed type as a partial feed, and another as a full-text feed.  Basically, you'd just be re-writing one of these feed types to ignore the setting you indicated on the "Reading Settings" admin screen.

I bet this could be done w/ a pretty simple plug-in.